# Partial derivative of coordinates with respect to function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, jacobian

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Then

$$\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j} = (\nabla f)^i_j$$

where $\nabla f$ is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $f$. When reading [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.588.4038&rep=rep1&type=pdf) I came across the expression

$$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial f^j}$$

Should I interpret this as

$$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial f^j} = ((\nabla f)^{-1})^i_j$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you can invert the problem $x^i = x^i(f)$. Clearly

$$
x^i = x^i(f^1(x),\cdots,f^n(x))
$$

Now apply the chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial f^k} \frac{\partial f^k}{\partial x^j} = (\nabla_f x)^{i}_{\;k}(\nabla_x f)^{k}_{\;j}  = \delta^i_j
$$

That means that

$$
\mathbb{1} = (\nabla_f x) (\nabla_x f)
$$

Or in other words

$$
\nabla_f x = (\nabla_x f)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Should be $\delta^i_j$ in your second equation, right? And dot product in the third?

Comment: @user76284 Yes, typo in the indices. But the third eqn is correct, it is the matrix product

Comment: Makes sense. I just always write the matrix product with a dot to make it clear I'm performing tensor contraction, and to distinguish it from the tensor product.